# Make UIViewController appear from bottom, then hide it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need a UIViewController to appear from the bottom of another view controller.

I also need the option to hide it again with a button, getting back to the previous view controller without reloading it.

Is it possible?

Comment: do you mean presenting the viewController?

Comment: Yes, with animation from the bottom of another view controller, and the possibility to make it go away.

Comment: If you are not using storyboards, my answer may help

Comment: Krishna's answer is correct under most circumstances, except when you need to retain the instance of the presented view controller, even when it is offscreen.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `presentViewController` and `dismissViewController` respectively but using this the presented view controller would be deallocated on dismiss which would mean it needs to be reloaded.

There is a somewhat hacky way around this, allow me to explain:

You can create an instance of the view controller you want to show from the bottom, then add it as a child of the current view controller. Then add it to the view heirarchy and animate it up from offscreen. Use the following code as a guide:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")
        self.addChildViewController(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        vc.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { 
            vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
        }
```

Then just reverse the animation to hide it on button press.

Comment: If I segue from the child view controller to other view controller, can I still animate back to the parent vc?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? My solution doesn't use segues...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. For this, you need to do the following.

```
let an:AnotherViewController = AnotherViewController() //the viewcontroller to present
self.present(an, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above code is for presenting

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above code is for dismissing from the presented view controller. If your button is inside the presented view controller. Then, this can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can create a View Controller and on click of any button you can open another view controller and present it modally.
In another view controller add one button and on click of that you can dismiss that view controller.

In first view controller in storyboard you can add action on button present modally and in next view controller if want to remove you can add call.
 dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)