# Swift 5 Present ViewController half way

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a layover VC programmatically.

However, I would like to keep the swipe down functionality of dismissing the VC and keep the background blur while ultimately presenting the VC half way from the bottom of view.

Presenting VC:

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SnackBarViewController())
    
present(navVC, animated: true)
```

I have found a way to present the VC half way like so, but I lose the swipe functionality and the background blur.

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SnackBarViewController())
navVC.transitioningDelegate = self
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(navVC, animated: true)

extension SettingsViewController : UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)
    }
}


class HalfSizePresentationController : UIPresentationController {
    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        get {
            guard let theView = containerView else {
                return CGRect.zero
            }

            return CGRect(x: 0, y: theView.bounds.height/2, width: theView.bounds.width, height: theView.bounds.height/2)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to present the VC half way in swift 5 without losing the presentation style format by default?

I have also heard of `UISheetPresentationController` using `detents` but im not entirely sure how to implement.

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106980/how-to-present-a-viewcontroller-on-half-screen)

[image]

base ios version 13.0. xcode version 12.5.1

Comment: Detents is pretty simple: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67988976/14351818

Comment: Note that it's only for iOS 15 and above though

Comment: So is there a better way to present the vc with default functionality half way?

Comment: Well `UISheetPresentationController`/`detents` is definitely the easiest and most polished, but there are libraries like [PanModal](https://github.com/slackhq/PanModal) that you can use

Comment: It's not about Swift 5 it's about UIKit version. You should communicate the Xcode version instead which is the faster way to know what is the base iOS SDK version and UIKit as well.

Comment: base ios version 13.0. xcode version 12.5.1